# How does JavaScript runtime works?

Tags: javascript

When 2 events are simultaneously  triggered in JavaScript, the javascript engine use a single queue (first procedure in, first out), or the engine internally create independent threads? and if is the second option(there could be concurrency problems due to this).

Thanks beforehand, for your time :)

Comment: I thought all event driven engines were single thread. The other option is thread blocking right? I only know php / js, so that could be wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript is single-threaded. Two events cannot occur completely simultaneously, so they are handled in the order in which they arrive.

Comment: I think so, but I think that's the only exception.

Comment: Yes WebWorkers get their own thread but when they are done the results are fed back to the queue which forces the output to be executed on the main thread once the stack has cleared. They are good for really heavy lifting like processing image data.